# Retrieve initials from a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been working on treating a sql table, and splitting the data. I've come to splitting some initials from the last name. The only problem is, the initials are spaced out. For example (data from my table)

- `Hanse J S P` > `J S P` are the initials
- `Gerson B D V` > `B D V` are the initials
- `J D Timberland` > `J D` are the initials

So basically, it's up to four initials, that can be either at the begin, middle, or end of the string. I'm at a loss as to how I should import these. into a seperate column where the result will be:

```
COL A | COL B
J S P | Jansen
B D V | Gerson
J D   | Timberland
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: And how do you define what the initials are?

Comment: This is sql server 2012, and the initials can be defined by the fact that they're one letter followed by a space.

Comment: Not always followed by a space, since _Hanse J S P_ would end in a P with no trailing space

Comment: That's true, I was mistaken. So, it's either a letter, followed by a space, followed by a letter, or the last character in a string.

Comment: `Hanse J S P` is not the same text as `J S P | Jansen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one uses `CHARINDEX` and recursive CTE to extract space delimited substrings from name:

- Find the substring before the first space
- Feed the remaining substring to the same CTE

Once you have the substrings, it is only a matter of gluing them back:

```
WITH yourdata(FullName) AS (
    SELECT 'Hanse J S P' UNION
    SELECT 'Gerson B D V' UNION
    SELECT 'J D Timberland' UNION
    SELECT 'TEST 1 TEST 2 TEST 3'
), cte AS (
    SELECT
        FullName,
        CASE WHEN Pos1 = 0 THEN FullName ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, Pos1 - 1) END AS LeftPart,
        CASE WHEN Pos1 = 0 THEN Null     ELSE SUBSTRING(FullName, Pos1 + 1, Pos2 - Pos1) END AS NextPart,
        1 AS PartSort
    FROM yourdata
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', FullName) AS Pos1, LEN(FullName) AS Pos2) AS CA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        FullName,
        CASE WHEN Pos1 = 0 THEN NextPart ELSE SUBSTRING(NextPart, 1, Pos1 - 1) END,
        CASE WHEN Pos1 = 0 THEN Null     ELSE SUBSTRING(NextPart, Pos1 + 1, Pos2 - Pos1) END,
        PartSort + 1
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', NextPart) AS Pos1, LEN(NextPart) AS Pos2) AS CA
    WHERE NextPart IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT yourdata.FullName, STUFF(CA1.XMLStr, 1, 1, '') AS Initials, STUFF(CA2.XMLStr, 1, 1, '') AS Names
FROM yourdata
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONCAT(' ', LeftPart)
    FROM cte
    WHERE FullName = yourdata.FullName AND LEN(LeftPart) = 1
    ORDER BY PartSort
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS CA1(XMLStr)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONCAT(' ', LeftPart)
    FROM cte
    WHERE FullName = yourdata.FullName AND LEN(LeftPart) > 1
    ORDER BY PartSort
    FOR XML PATH('')
) AS CA2(XMLStr)
```

Result:

```
| FullName             | Initials | Names          |
|----------------------|----------|----------------|
| Gerson@B@D@V         | B D V    | Gerson         |
| Hanse@J@S@P          | J S P    | Hanse          |
| J@D@Timberland       | J D      | Timberland     |
| TEST@1@TEST@2@TEST@3 | 1 2 3    | TEST TEST TEST |
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather hamfisted way of doing it by abusing the `Parsename` function. The big caveat here is that `Parsename` is limited to 4 tokens so `J S P Jansen` will work but `J S P C Jansen` or `John J S P Jansen` will not.

```
With parsedname AS
(
  SELECT
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 1) name1,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 2) name2,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 3) name3,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 4) name4
   FROM yourtable
)
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN LEN(name4) = 1 THEN name4 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name3) = 1 THEN name3 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name2) = 1 THEN name2 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name1) = 1 THEN name1 ELSE '' END as initials,
   CASE WHEN LEN(name1) > 1 THEN name1 
      WHEN LEN(name2) > 1 THEN name2
      WHEN LEN(name3) > 1 THEN name3
      WHEN LEN(name4) > 1 THEN name4
      END as surname
FROM parsedname
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle of this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c4db/1)

```
CREATE TABLE NAMES (name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES ('J S P Jansen');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES ('B D V Gerson');
INSERT INTO NAMES VALUES ('J D Timberland');

With parsedname AS
(
  SELECT
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 1) name1,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 2) name2,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 3) name3,
      PARSENAME(replace(name, ' ', '.'), 4) name4
   FROM names
)
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN LEN(name4) = 1 THEN name4 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name3) = 1 THEN name3 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name2) = 1 THEN name2 ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name1) = 1 THEN name1 ELSE '' END as initials,
   CASE WHEN LEN(name1) > 1 THEN name1 
      WHEN LEN(name2) > 1 THEN name2
      WHEN LEN(name3) > 1 THEN name3
      WHEN LEN(name4) > 1 THEN name4
      END as surname
FROM parsedname

+----------+------------+
| initials |  surname   |
+----------+------------+
| JSP      | Jansen     |
| BDV      | Gerson     |
| JD       | Timberland |
+----------+------------+
```

If a space is needed in between those letters you can just flip around that CASE statement to something like:

```
TRIM(CASE WHEN LEN(name4) = 1 THEN name4 + ' ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name3) = 1 THEN name3 + ' ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name2) = 1 THEN name2 + ' ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN LEN(name1) = 1 THEN name1 + ' ' ELSE '' END) as initials
```

[SQLFiddle with the spaces](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8c4db/2)

```
+----------+------------+
| initials |  surname   |
+----------+------------+
| J S P    | Jansen     |
| B D V    | Gerson     |
| J D      | Timberland |
+----------+------------+
```

Comment: If the string is "A ! ? B Whatever', your result will be "A!?B" instead of "A B".

Comment: Well... we're just going to hope that doesn't happen.

Comment: I think initials are supposed to be letters. One of his requirements is to add a space in between the initials.

Comment: @NicVerAZ good catch. I added a bit at the bottom to get the spaces back from all the parsed and mangled words. It's like Frankenstein's monster.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to JNevil's answer (+1), but not limited to 4 tokens.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('Hanse J S P')
,('Gerson B D V')
,('J D Timberland')
,('J D Timberland / J R R Tolkien')


Select A.SomeCol
      ,ColA = ltrim(
              concat(IIF(len(Pos1)=1,' '+Pos1,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos2)=1,' '+Pos2,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos3)=1,' '+Pos3,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos4)=1,' '+Pos4,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos5)=1,' '+Pos5,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos6)=1,' '+Pos6,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos7)=1,' '+Pos7,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos8)=1,' '+Pos8,null)
                    ,IIF(len(Pos9)=1,' '+Pos9,null)
                    )
              )
      ,ColB = ltrim(
              concat(IIF(Pos1 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos1,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos2 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos2,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos3 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos3,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos4 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos4,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos5 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos5,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos6 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos6,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos7 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos7,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos8 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos8,null)
                    ,IIF(Pos9 not Like '[a-z]',' '+Pos9,null)
                    )
              )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos6 = xDim.value('/x[6]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos7 = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos8 = xDim.value('/x[8]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Pos9 = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,' ','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                           ColA            ColB
Hanse J S P                       J S P           Hanse
Gerson B D V                      B D V           Gerson
J D Timberland                    J D             Timberland
J D Timberland / J R R Tolkien    J D / J R R     Timberland / Tolkien
```

Comment: This is a pretty nifty take on XML string splitting to come back to this answer. I like this.

Comment: Also, to anyone else coming across this question, I believe this answer can be taken all the way back to SQL 2008 if `iif()` is replaced with `CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <trueValue> ELSE <falseValue> END`.

Answer (score 1):

I used some built-in functions for this. The general idea is to use `string_split` to split the string into rows, use `ROW_NUMBER` to save the order according to length and the char(s) position in the string, then use `FOR XML PATH()` to concatenate from rows to a single column.

```
--Assume your data structure
DECLARE @temp TABLE (thestring varchar(1000))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 ('Hanse J S P'), ('Gerson B D V'), ('J D Timberland')

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY thestring ORDER BY thestring, LEN(value) ASC, pos ASC) [order]
        FROM (
                SELECT *      
                    , value AS [theval]
                    , CHARINDEX(CASE WHEN len(value) = 1 THEN ' ' + value ELSE value END, thestring) AS [pos]
                FROM @temp CROSS APPLY string_split(thestring, ' ')
            )  AS dT
)
SELECT ( SELECT value + ' ' AS [text()]
                 FROM cte 
                WHERE cte.thestring = T.thestring
                  AND LEN(theval) = 1
                FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS [COL A]
      ,( SELECT value + ' ' AS [text()]
                 FROM cte 
                WHERE cte.thestring = T.thestring
                  AND LEN(theval) > 1
                FOR XML PATH('')
       ) AS [COL B]
  FROM @temp T 
GROUP BY thestring
```

Produces output:

```
COL A   COL B
-----   -----
B D V   Gerson 
J S P   Hanse 
J D     Timberland
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `string_split()` isn't available in SQL 2012. It was added in SQL 2016.

Comment: @Shawn ahh didn't see that comment, was going off the question.  Sorry it doesn't help OP.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server do you have? Is STRING_SPLIT() available?

If yes, split using the space as a delimiter, iterate through the resulting strings, evaluate their length and concatenate a result string with the string when said string is one character in length and is a letter.

Add a space before unless the result string is so far empty.

If STRING_SPLIT() is not available... Well... Here are a few solutions:

[T-SQL split string based on delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768321/t-sql-split-string-based-on-delimiter)

-- Addendum

To your second part of the question (which did not originally exist when I originally posted my reply) where you would like to isolate the non-initials part into a second column, I would basically separate two blocks of logic with two result strings based on the length of each element.

Note: this is not going to be very elegant in pre-2016 SQL Server and may even require a **CURSOR** (sigh)

I know I am going to be downvoted for mentioning a cursor.